# Replace getter for all attributes in CoreData Entity

Tags: ios, core-data

In my CoreData model I have an Entity `Article` with 20 properties, and a child entity `Variant`, with a to-one relationship "master" to `Article`. So `Variant` has all attributes of `Article` parent class, but I want that if an attribute is `nil`, the getter should return the one of the master `Article`.

In code:

```
- (NSString *)getSomeAttribute {

    NSString *tmp = self.someAttribute;
    if (tmp == nil)
        tmp = self.master.someAttribute;

    return tmp;
}
```

I don't want to write 20 getters like this, is there a way to write a "general" getter for all attributes at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't skip the getters, because if you don't implement them, Core Data will generate them. What you can do is factor all of the custom code into one core method and have your other getters call that. You still end up with a bunch of getters, but they're one-liners. Something like this (warning, typed into a web browser and not compiled):

```
- (id)valueForKeyFromSelfOrMaster:(NSString *)key
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:key];
    id value = [self primitiveValueForKey:key];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:key];

    if (value == nil) {
        value = [self.master valueForKey:key];
    }
    return value;
}

- (NSString *)someAttribute
{
    return [self valueForKeyFromSelfOrMaster:@"someAttribute"];
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but I would like to avoid single getters for portability and modularity reasons. I'm just playing with the runtime libraries, I'm trying to build getters at runtime, I will let you know asap ;) Thanks Tom.

Comment: If you only have to do it 20 times, I think the solution is to cut-n-paste 20 times.